# GWT insert one element into another (span into anchor)

Tags: java, html, gwt, anchor

I am trying to create the following in GWT:

```
<a class="blahblahblah"><span>some text</span></a>
```

I have an `Anchor`, and an `InlineHTML` with my content, but I can't find a way to simply insert the span into the anchor (I need to retain a reference to the span because I want to update its text.

The equivalent in javascript (using jQuery) would be:

```
var myAnchor = $('<a class="blahblahblah"></a>'),
    mySpan   = $('<span>some text</span>');
myAnchor.append(mySpan);
```

How can I achieve this in GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can set id attributes for these elements(Anchor and inlineHTML) and then use `DOM.getElementById().appendChild()`. look into DOM javadoc for different options.

**Update**

If you don't want to set Id's, you can use getElement() method of `Anchor` and `HTML` classes.

```
DOM.appendChild(anchor.getElement(), html.getElement());
```

Comment: I don't want to be adding IDs to everything, because that's a bit of an abuse. There really should be a way to do this.

Comment: @GTF Updated the answer accordingly.